# Easily convert MM/DD to DD/MM including time in excel

Tags: excel, date, time, format

Need to easily convert Excel date-time format from `mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` to `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

After the conversion, it needs to still be in the proper date-time format so it can be sorted correctly according to date and time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get this working is to use the below formula and ensure you have configured the Format Cell > Number > Category value correctly.

### Formula

In this example A1 is the source cell. Place this in A2:

```
=VALUE(DATE(TEXT(A1,"yyyy"),TEXT(A1,"dd"),TEXT(A1,"mm"))+TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")))
```

This simply reads the date-time and as it rebuilds the date-time number, swaps the day and month numbers around. Obviously this can be used for either situation as is.

### Cell Format

Also need to ensure your Format Cell > Number > Category is set to Custom and using the right format:

e.g.

[24hr format] - `dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss`

[12hr format] - `dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

*or whatever variation you need for your location*

### Alternatives

#### Text Format

If you just wanted to make it text and swap the day and month around you can use

[24hr format] - `=TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")`

[12hr format] - `=TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yy HH:mm:ss AM/PM")`

Comment: The Text-to-Columns command allows you to switch from MDY to DMY but the real danger is MDY data that was imported and ambiguously converted to the wrong value (e.g. 07-Apr-2015 instead of 04-Jul-2015). Better to import TXT or CSV data using Data ► External Data ► From Text and specify the MDY/DMY format on the third screen of the Text Import Wizard. Getting the correct date values from double-clicking a CSV in an Explorer pane is more coincidence than fact.

Comment: p.s. the Text Format Alternatives at the bottom seem to provide the opposite of what the question's narrative requests.

Comment: Yeah I realised a few hours after posting this my solution is actually wrong. The answer above is incorrect as it fails if the day (being read as month) is over 12. I do have a solution though, which I'll update the post for in a bit.